# How to extract a key value pair from ps command

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, ps

I am trying to extract application name from `ps` command like this:

```
ps -af -u sas |grep "java"| grep -v "grep"
```

and it produces the following:

```
sas 24431     1  0 Oct10 ?        00:51:08 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.25.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Denv=DEV -Dapp.name=myApp -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Dlog.dir=/apps/java/logs
```

I tried using `egrep` but doesn't seems to be working:

```
ps -af -u sas|grep "java"| grep -v "grep"| egrep -o "-Dapp.name"
```

How can I get only the `-Dapp.name` value "myApp"?

Comment: if the `grep` pattern begins with `-`, you need to put it after the `-e` option. Otherwise, it will be treated as an option. But that will just match the word `-Dapp.name`, not the part after it.

Comment: alternately: `grep -o -- -Dapp.name`

Comment: you can use ``grep [j]ava`` to avoid command ``grep -v "grep"`` (tested on bash)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
ps -af -u sas | awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "}; /-Dapp.name/'
```

Answer (score 8):

You're not showing the error message you are getting but it's probably

> grep: unknown devices method

That's because, like all or at least most other command line programs, `grep` assumes that anything that starts with a `-` is an option and tries to parse it as such. In this case, `-D` is used to instruct `grep` on how to deal with a device file (see `man grep` for details). One way to get around this is to use `--` which tells `grep` that anything following is not an option flag.

Combining that with the PCRE capability of GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
ps -af -u sas | grep -v grep | grep -Po -- '*-\KDapp.name=[^\s]+'
```

The regular expression searches for a `-` and discards it (`\K`), then the string `Dapp.name=` followed by as many non-space characters as possible. The output is:

```
Dapp.name=myApp
```

If you want the `myApp` part saved in a variable, I would search for that alone:

```
ps -af -u sas | grep -v grep | grep -Po -- '-Dapp.name=\K[^\s]+'
```

To assign it to a variable:

```
$ app="$(ps -af -u sas | grep -v grep | grep -Po -- '-Dapp.name=\K[^\s]+')"
$ echo $app
myApp
```

However, you should never `grep` the output of `ps` for this kind of thing, that's what [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) is for:

```
app="$(pgrep -a java | grep -Po -- '^Dapp.name=\K[^\s]+')"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ps -af -u sas | sed -n '/[j]ava/s/.*-Dapp\.name=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 3):

More complicated than the other answers, but this uses `getopt` to handle the parsing for you. Yet another alternative.

```
getopt -aql 'Dapp.name:' $(\
    ps -af -u sas | grep java | grep -v grep | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8-\
) | cut -d"'" -f2
```

1. your command: `ps -af -u sas | grep java | grep -v grep`
2. `tr -s ' '` "squeezes" multiple spaces into a single space in preparation for `cut`
3. `cut -d' ' -f8-` splits the line by spaces and grabs all the fields after 8 inclusive, result is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.25.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Denv=DEV -Dapp.name=myApp -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Dlog.dir=/apps/java/logs`
4. `getopts -aql 'Dapp.name:' $(...)` parses the command options and outputs only the longname that matches `Dapp.name` who has a value (denoted by the `:`), result is `--Dapp.name 'myApp' --`
5. `cut -d"'" -f2` grabs the stuff in the single quotes
6. Result is: `myApp`

Answer (score 3):

Any time you use `ps … | grep …` and need to exclude grep from the results, you're doing it wrong.

The zeroth rule of parsing the output of `ps` is to use more reliable tools such as `pgrep` if available. If you have pgrep, then `pgrep -f java` lists all the processes running the command `java`. The option `-l` adds the command line for each process.

To extract the argument to `-Dapp.name`, you can use sed. Match the whole line, arrange to stuff the interesting part in a group, and print out that group.

```
pgrep -lf java | sed -n 's/^.*-Dapp\.name=\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/p'
```

The first rule of parsing the output of `ps` is to use the option `-o` to select the fields that you need. Here, you're only interested in the command arguments, so print only that.

```
ps -e -o args= | sed -n 's/^.*-Dapp\.name=\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pgrep` instead of `ps` like so:

```
$ pgrep -fa java | grep -op "(<=-Dapp.name=)\w+"
```

This will return all the processes that match `java` and then filter those out showing only the ones that contain `-Dapp.name=`. The   last bit, `\w+` will show the program name, assuming that it contains no spaces.

**NOTE:** The `-P` switch to `grep` enlists the ability to specify things using [PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/). Not all version of `grep` support it but most do that are included with more modern versions of Linux.

If you want the entire key/value output then change things like so:

```
$ pgrep -fa java | grep -oP -- "-Dapp.name=\w+"
```